Начинаю изучать C++. Столкнулся с примером программы прикрепленной ниже и не понимаю почему она так работает
Хочу понять как работает программа и почему выводит не все введенные символы последовательно, а все разом, и по нажатию кнопки enter. Не понимаю почему программа работает так потому что думаю что в одну переменную char нельзя запихнуть бесконечное количество символов.
# include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    char ch;
    int count = 0;
    std::cin.get(ch);



    while (std::cin.fail() == false)

    {
        std::cout << ch;
        ++count;
        std::cin.get(ch);
    }

    std::cout << ch << std::endl;
    std::cout << count;
    return 0;
};  


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

Потому что ввод буферизован...

"в одну переменную char нельзя запихнуть бесконечное количество символов" - а тут в нее запихивается один char, который сразу выводится, затем второй, перезаписывая предыдущий и т.д.
